# Easiest way of finding photos with no tags using the Flickr API

Tags: metadata, flickr

I'm working on a small project to help me tag content on Flickr.

I've been looking through the API and there's obvious ways to search for tagged content, but not a simple way of finding what content hasn't been tagged (without just looping through image ID's till I find one with no tag).

Has anyone come across this in the past and found an easy work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flickr.photos.getUntagged](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getUntagged.html) will do that for your own photos. I'm pretty sure that there's no way to do it for more general searches, other than brute force.